# Non-constant polynomials with real coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

> We say that a polynomial is positivist if it can be written as a product of two non-constant polynomials with real coefficients $\geq 0$. Let be $f(x)$ a non-null polynomial with constant coefficient non-null such that $f(x^n)$ is positivist for some positive integer $n$. Prove that $f(x)$ is positivist.

The problem statement lacked the hypothesis that $ f $ has a degree greater than $ 1 $ (or, alternatively, that the constant coefficient of $ f $ is non-zero). The conclusion of the problem, as proposed, is false for $ f (x) = cx $, with $ c $ positive integer.

Would anyone have formal proof, or a counterexample to the problem?

Comment: Your $f(x) = cx$ does not satisfy "with constant coefficient non-null".

Comment: Hint: if $f(x^n) = g(x)h(x)$ and all powers of $x$ in $g,h$ are multiples of $n$ then the same factorization works for $f(x)$. Otherwise look for the smallest $x^p$ term in $g, h$ with $p$ not a multiple of $n$.